# Manual name mangling in C

Tags: c, identifier, name-mangling

I would like to implement some kind of name mangling for a C interface. I will have functions and types like

```
struct Foo;
struct Foo* Foo_create(struct Bar* bar);
void Foo_destroy(struct Foo* obj);
struct Foo_InnerClass;
...
```

Now, the _ is used extensivliy in all standard c typedefs, so the scheme would not work good if these typedefs are used. GCC and MSVC seems to accept names using $. Would that work? Are there any other acceptet characters that I can use?

EDIT:

I want to do this because

- It avoids duplicated names
- It emphases what class an identifier belongs to
- It makes it possible to automatically generate C++ interface

EDIT 2:

Reserve an ordinary letter will compile everywhere, but it can also be confusing:

```
struct Foo* FooIcreate(struct Bar* bar);
```

EDIT 3:

The symbol may differ depending on target platform, but on that platform, it must not collide with C++ name mangling.

EDIT 4:

It is forbidden to begin an identifier with a digit. So what about:

```
struct Foo* Foo_1_create(struct Bar* bar);
```

Comment: What do you want to do, hide `Foo_InnerClass`?

Comment: @larsmans No, rather emphase that InnerClass belongs to Foo in a machine parsable way.

Comment: My first question to @user877329 is : do you want to implement same name mangling algorithm that's used by GCC and MSVC?

Comment: @PrototypeStark No, because the calling convention differs. If there was no such problem, i could use C++ directly, now i cannot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In lack of a better sulotion, i think i will use

```
_1
```

as separator

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you are doing this, or exactly what the goal is, but most C libraries use some more or less mnemonic prefix.

A plain `$` would be awful, since it's a) very uncommon, C identifiers typically start with a letter or underscore and contain only letters, digits and underscores and b) doesn't say anything about to what the symbol belongs.

A library like glib has a `g_` prefix for all functions, a `g` for its types, and `G_` for macros. GTK+ is similar, it uses `gtk_` and so on.

Comment: Very uncommon makes it good because no one would use it in his own name.

Comment: @user877329: `$` is not allowed by ISO C.

Comment: @larsmans which is the only bad thing about it (as long as the linker and assembler accepts it).

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `$`. The C standard does not allow them in identifiers, even though C compilers such as GCC accept them for backward compatibility with 1980s C compilers (mostly VAX/VMS C, I believe).

How about using double underscores?

```
struct Foo__InnerClass;
```

**EDIT**: ok, this prevents your program from ever working in a mixed C/C++ program (see [C++ underscore rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier)), so it's a bad idea. How about a trailing underscore:

```
struct Foo_InnerClass_
```

Comment: Isn't that undefined behaviour?

Comment: @KerrekSB, no not for C, but for C++. If there is any chance that the interfaces are also used from C++ this isn't a good idea. They need that for ... name mangling.

Comment: @JensGustedt Neither GCC ver 3 or later or VC seems to use __ .

Comment: @user877329, so what? Just because some compilers don't use it, it doesn't mean that other wouldn't or even that the same compilers wouldn't do it in other versions.

Answer (score 1):

It's fine, though I like to use struct Foo_t to show it's a type.

My preference is to keep double _ (__) for something special or a "private" indicator and not regular use. This is pure personal preference though any local coding standards may say something on the subject.

The $ is iffy... while some compilers accept it some don't. It is not a historic part of the C language. While common in some operating systems and languages, not so much in others. History: the big three historic specials of IBM mainframes are $, #, and @ where _ was NOT a member of the club and VMS loves $.

Comment: The `_t` suffix is reserved by POSIX, AFAIR, and `__` are reserved by C++ to do name mangling.

Answer (score 0):

It would not use dollar sign in identifiers because it is:

- Uncommon, I didn't see it anywhere
- Because of the first reason it would confuse users of your code, and maybe even some tools, editors, etc.
- It is not supported for all targets, for example:

  ```
  echo 'void foo$bar(void) { }' | arm-elf-gcc -xc -c -
  ```

  Outputs:

  ```
  <stdin>:1: error: stray '$' in program
  <stdin>:1: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'bar'
  ```

Personally I would use some kind of module prefixes, like in your first code snippet. If you afraid of name collisions with other libraries you can add one more global prefix, like `mylib_foo_create`.

Comment: The problem with _ is that size_t or int32_t then is interpreted as member t in class size and int32 respectivly.

Comment: @user877329 Is it really an issue? Are you trying to parse you code automatically to extract type information or something like that?

Comment: Even if so, `size_t` and `int32_t` identifiers are part of C language standard and you could handle them in a special way.

Comment: @EldarAbsalimov Yes I could, but it is ugly.